# ¿Como salgo de este Thread?

Tags: java, hilos

Este código es como un cronometro que cuenta hasta 10, el problema es que después ya no me deja continuar introduciendo texto con System.out.println ni nada, si no que se termina de ejecutar el código completo, ¿como puedo salir de el?

```
public class segundero {
    public static void main(String [] arg){
        //  codigo del segundero
        int segundos = 0;           
        for(segundos=0;segundos<10;segundos++){
                System.out.println(segundos);
                delaySegundo(); 
        }
    }
    private static void delaySegundo(){
        try{

            Thread.sleep(1000);

        }catch(InterruptedException e){

        }

        System.out.println("texto nuevo");
        //  Aquí termina el codigo del segundero
    }    
}
```

Comment: Que es lo que quieres lograr? según tu código lo que entiendo es que, quieres contar hasta 10 dentro del for, y dentro de el tienes un sleep de 1 segundo, para que así le tome 10 segundos en recorrer el for, eso es lo que quieres?

Comment: no, mas bien quiero salir de ahí y que el código continué, por que no importa lo que ponga después, mi código se queda atascado allí, por ejemplo el System.out de abajo si lo pongo fuera no me lo reconoce, ¿como hago para que al final de esos 10 segundos se imprima algo nuevo?

Comment: Me dices que si pones el System.out.println fuera del for no lo imprime?!, pues debería, ahora te pregunto, basado en tu código cuantas veces te imprime "texto nuevo" (y me refiero al que esta en el metodo delaySegundo)??. Tambien el sout del "segundos" te esta dando del 1 al 10 !?

Comment: Como dice @Rostan debería hacerte los 2 println, si te imprime 10 veces el valor de segundo y texto nuevo te va bien. ¿No te imprime nada? porque en el código que muestras no se ve nada raro. De todas maneras, en vez de InterruptedException pon Exception solo así pillas todas excepciones, no te esté saltando otra de otro tipo (aunque no lo creo)

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta... el código, como comentan los compañeros funciona perfectamente, pero no se cual es tu intención en si. Si pones el código completo de lo que estas haciendo, genial, ya que el código que está puesto funciona perfectamente.